# Choosing Projected Coordinate Sytem for Australia in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, geometry, australia

I have a data from Australia which has the Geographic Coordinate System of GCS_GDA_1994 but has no Projection System.

I need to calculate (Geomerty) the area/length in part of my model but for that we need a Projected Coordinate Sytem.

The idea is to create a GP Tool in Portal out of it.

I have tried possible projections but I do not know which one is the correct one

Comment: Don't forget to take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to this site.  Where in Australia is your area of interest? What projections have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

In Australia most people would use one of the Map Grid of Australia (MGA) Zones for most work at local government scale.

The MGA Zone to use will depend on where within Australia you are working.

For state and national scale work most people would use Albers or Lambert Conic Conformal (LCC).

Comment: Thank you very for your feedback. I hae tried to find that in the list of Projection systems but it is not available.

Comment: Did you look under Projected Coordinate Systems>National Grids>Australia?

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. Yes I did but it is hard to decide which is suitable as we are going to use this data in WebGIS and Portal it should fit.

Comment: THank you for all comments. I was able to solve this question through contacting with the main data provider. apprently it is not possibe to define a general Projected Coordinate System and it is better to use a spesific Projected Coordinate Systems for each region e.g. Melbourne it is "EPSG Projection 28355 - GDA94 / MGA zone 55 " and so on.

Comment: @radek three of those are Lamberts - only one is Albers - I'm not at computer to see all options and I've never needed to choose nationally - I use Lamberts in SA, Albers in WA and QLD because that's what the locals use.

Comment: My apologies @PolyGeo. Got a bit confused. Indeed there seems to be only one Albers:  `GDA_1994_Australia_Albers`. Thanks for input!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this question through contacting with the main data provider. Apprently it is not possibe to define a general Projected Coordinate System and it is better to use a spesific Projected Coordinate Systems for each region e.g. Melbourne it is "EPSG Projection 28355 - GDA94 / MGA zone 55 " and so on.